# addClass hidden from ng-click angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jqlite

Here is my code HTML :

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Enregistrer</button>
```

I want to make the button hidden by adding class hidden from the HTML element, like it is done with JQUERY and backbone:

```
  $('a[data-actions="save"]').addClass('hidden')
```

I have tried this :

```
angular.element($scope.save)
```

but it didn't work, inspite it works if I use the html ID, like this one :

```
 var tempItem = document.getElementById('name');
      angular.element(tempItem)
        .addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Where the `$('a[data-actions="save"]').addClass('hidden')` come from? I don't see that link in your html?

Comment: I used to do it with Jquery and backbone, but now I am using angular

Comment: just initialize scope varibale and use ng-show to hide show button..

Comment: you should not do any DOM manipulation in controller, use `ng-class`instead.

Comment: It's not relevant. To each element do you want to add the class? The button? the link? Do you mean the when the user will click on the button, it will add the class `hidden` to the `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use data to alter the appearance in form of show/hide.

ng-show and ng-hide are good for this. And sometimes ng-if also comes handy if the hidden or to-be hidden element are heavy in terms of DOM.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {

    $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.shown = !$scope.shown;

    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <p ng-show="shown">Hello World</p>
  <button type="button" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Enregistrer</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to add a class in your button

```
<button type="button" ng-class="{'hidden':selectedClass}" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Enregistrer</button>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.selectedClass = false;
$scope.save = function(){
    $scope.selectedClass = ! $scope.selectedClass;
}
```

Hope this is help you.